# Error Link2005 in visual 2005

Tags: c, include, pragma

I wrote a c program in Visual C++.

test2.cpp

```
    #pragma startup pragmaEgFun1
    void pragmaEgFun1(){
    printf("Hello 1");
    }
```

test1.cpp

```
    #include "test2.cpp"
    int main{
    printf("Hello 2");
    }
```

This program was to test pragma preprocessor directive. But i am getting an error Error

> error LNK2005: "void __cdecl pragmaEgFun1(void)"
>   (?pragmaEgFun1@@YAXXZ) already defined in test1.obj

Comment: err... including .cpp file. Please avoid!

Comment: Are you compiling both `.cpp` files? Since you're including `test2.cpp` into `test1.cpp` you must ensure that Visual Studio 2005 doesn't try and compile them together (i.e. `test2.cpp` is flagged not to be compiled in the solution).

Comment: how to ensure that VC++ compiles test1.cpp only, because visual c++ has this option to build the project and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to solve this:

1. Simply remove the `#include` line from `test1.cpp`. Since you are not calling that function, you don't need to include it anyway. The `pragma startup` should take care that the function is called and it will be available because VC will link it.
2. Rename `test2.cpp` to `test2.h` and include that one in `test1.cpp`. This would be not a best practice though, because functions are normally not supposed to be in header files, even though it is allowed by the compiler.
3. You can place the function from `test2.cpp` directly into `test1.cpp`, as you don't really need it anyway.

To answer your comment - normally you put functions into `.c/.cpp` files and declarations, prototypes, definitions, macros etc. into the `.h` files. This is not dictated by the compiler though, but good coding practices help to avoid such problems as you posted in your question.

Comment: your 2nd solution, can you tell me where to place the function definitions and how to use them in main function using a header file.

Comment: I updated my answer. I mentioned solution two only for completeness, as it is not really good practice, and you can easily run into linking problems. Exactly the type of error you posted your question in the first place.